# MySQL Identify Faulty Column

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am making an application in *node.js*

In a MySQL table, I have multiple columns that need to be Unique. When I insert a value that is not unique, an error is returned.

- *How do I identify which column is giving me the error? For example, I need the username and email column to be unique, and if I insert an existing username I get a "ER_DUP_ENTRY" error code.*

The problem here is that I am not sure how to identify which column is giving me the error. The error also contains a message:

```
sqlMessage: 'Duplicate entry \'GrimReaper\' for key \'username_UNIQUE\''
```

Of course, I could some how extract the last part of the message ( *username_UNIQUE* ), *but I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this?*

*The reason I need this* is to be able to send the client a message indicating that the specified username or email is unavailable.

Thanks!

Comment: _Another alternative_: Why don't just test after the user fill the input field, if the entered data exists or not. Using AJAX ..

Comment: The last value is the name of the unique index for which the constraint fails. If you want a better name in the output then choose better names for your indexes.

Comment: I never said I wanted better names, I was just wondering if there is a proper way of getting the name of the column, without extracting it from here. It's not hard to do, I'm just curious. Also the column is named: "username" and I think that's as good as it can get for something that stores a "username". Regarding the alternative Hamza mentioned, I'd rather not query the database, it is more efficient to retrieve the error from MySQL.

Comment: To me you are on the right tract. Since your way of identifying the duplicate column is simple and reliable, just go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all you have available is the error code and the error message text. There is no other information available from a MySQL error.

If you need the specific column, you need to parse it from the message text.